Why is the snapshot retrieval returning null even though the image appears to be successfully cached?
I'm trying to implement image caching in my Android app using Coil. The goal is to ensure images are cached in both memory and disk, and then retrieve the cached image as a Uri. However, I'm encountering an issue where the path is null when attempting to retrieve the cached image snapshot.
Here’s my getImage function:
private suspend fun getImage(imageUri: String, force: Boolean): String {
        Log.d("TAG", "getImage: $imageUri")

        // Explicitly set a custom cache key
        val cacheKey = imageUri.hashCode().toString()

        // Create the ImageRequest
        val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context).diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .data(imageUri)
            .diskCacheKey(cacheKey).memoryCacheKey(cacheKey) // Ensure the key is not null
            .build()

        // Ensure the image is cached
        with(context.imageLoader) {
            if (force) {
                diskCache?.remove(cacheKey)
                memoryCache?.remove(MemoryCache.Key(cacheKey))
                Log.d("TAG", "Cache cleared for key: $cacheKey")
            }

            val result = execute(request)
            if (result is ErrorResult) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Image caching failed: ${result.throwable}")
                throw result.throwable
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Image successfully cached with key: $cacheKey")
            }
        }

        // Retrieve the cached image
        val path = try {
            context.imageLoader.diskCache?.openSnapshot(cacheKey)?.use { snapshot ->
                val imageFile = snapshot.data.toFile()
                Log.d("TAG", "Image file created: ${imageFile.absolutePath}")

                val contentUri = getUriForFile(
                    context,
                    "dev.jay.momentbox.widget.fileprovider",
                    imageFile
                )
                Log.d("TAG", "Content URI created: $contentUri")

                contentUri.toString()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Error retrieving image from cache: $imageUri", e)
            null
        }

        // Log and return result
        if (path == null) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Path is null; image not found in cache.")
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't find cached file for the provided URI")
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Retrieved image path: $path")
        }

        return path
    }

Here’s the log output:
2024-11-15 21:24:10.216  9155-9227  TAG                     dev.jay.momentbox                    D  getImage: content://media/picker_get_content/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000015329
2024-11-15 21:24:10.217  9155-9198  WM-Processor            dev.jay.momentbox                    D  Work WorkGenerationalId(workSpecId=8c15c3a4-df4b-4828-9429-79f8d50901f5, generation=0) is already enqueued for processing
2024-11-15 21:24:10.505  9155-9227  TAG                     dev.jay.momentbox                    D  Image successfully cached with key: -614239324
2024-11-15 21:24:10.512  9155-9227  TAG                     dev.jay.momentbox                    E  Path is null; image not found in cache.

